Using multiple headers from a Word template with officedown
I'm trying to create a Word document using RMarkdown and the officedown package. I have a Word template (Word_template.docx) with multiple headers that are defined in different sections that arent linked to the previous header. I want to use these headers in my RMarkdown document; for each chapter I would like to have a uniquely defined header.
Here's my simplified rmarkdown code:
---
title: "Test"
author: " "
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    number_sections: true
    reference_docx: "Word_template.docx"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(officedown)
library(officer)
```


\newpage

# Chapter 1

\newpage

# Chapter 2

\newpage

# Chapter 3

\newpage

# Chapter 4

The problem is that only the first two headers are applied correctly from the Word template. The remaining headers are not applied.
Here's a picture of the word template.

picture word template Google drive
Here's the output.

picture output Google Drive
How can I use multiple headers from a Word template with officedown or perhaps other packages? Is there a way to specify which header to use for each section of the document?
Any help would be appreciated!

I'm not super clear on what you want to achieve. Is this something you could do by defining fonts such as header1_font <- fp_text(font.size = 16) and then using in r markdown like # r ftext("Chapter 1", prop = header1_font) ?
